# C++ object management without pointers

Tags: c++

It is often repeated to not manage your own memory when possible. When writing an object that manages other objects in a map or vector, how then should objects be created and added to it.

If your object management using new and pointers, this make sense.

```
// Manager::AddObj(Obj* obj);
// std::map<int, Obj*>
Obj* obj = new Obj();
obj->InitializeThings();
manager.AddObj(obj);
obj->CanStillDoThings();
```

But when not using pointers, it's kinda ... wrong. And I'm not sure what the right way to do it is. The object you make initially only serves to be copied into the map. Also if you create that object outside of the manager, you sort of lose it.. Because you don't want to put it into the manager and then be working on a stale object..!

```
// Manager::AddObj(Obj& obj);
// std::map<int, Obj>
Obj obj;
obj.DoAllocateyThings(); // copy ctor better be right!
manager.AddObj(obj);
obj.DoMoreStuff(); // this is not the same obj as the managed one!
Obj* real_obj = manager.GetObj();
```

I guess a solution is to use the manager to create the object. Then the ugliness is only inside the manager.

```
Obj* Manager::CreateObj(){
    Obj obj;
    this->AddObj(1, obj);
    return this->GetObj(1);
}
```

Is there yet a better way?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Reproducible, Complete Example. For what I can see you're probably creating an unnecesary copy of `obj` in `manager.AddObj()`. How `manager.AddObj();` is?

Comment: Since you cannot have a map of references, how else could `AddObj` function? It will make a copy unless you use ptrs, and no one likes ptrs..

Comment: You can offload the memory management to a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: @pbuzz007 What does `manager.AddObj` return?  As a matter of fact, what does `map.insert()` (which I'm assuming you're using under the hood) return?  I know what it is -- I would like to know if you ever considered using the return value of `insert()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm good idea. I supposed this question boils down to - is it a good idea to store complex objects in a container, or just pointers to them.

Comment: Complexity of the object is not a deciding factor of whether to use pointers.  Pointers should be used if you need to use pointers, nothing more than that.  Otherwise use objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that `AddObj` calls `std::map::insert`.  If so, then you can do something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Obj
{
    public:
      int num;
      Obj(int n = 0) : num(n) {}
};

std::map<int, Obj> m_ObjectMap;

Obj& CreateObj(int value)
{
    Obj obj(value);
    auto pr = m_ObjectMap.insert({1, obj});
    return pr.first->second;
}

int main()
{
   Obj& r =  CreateObj(4);
   std::cout << r.num << "\n";
   
   // verify that r is the actual reference to the object in the map
   r.num = 100;
   std::cout << m_ObjectMap[1].num << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
4
100
```

The return value for [std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is a `std::pair` denoting an iterator to the inserted item, and a `bool` that represents whether a new item was inserted or not.

Since a `std::map` iterator is a `std::pair<key, data>`, all that is required is to return a reference to the `second` of this pair.

The only issue is if the item is removed from the `std::map`, you will be left with a dangling reference if you hold onto it.  That's a different story.